# Selecting a mysql row from one table based on select statement in another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select a tshirts which the user has not voted on yet (from another table "votes")

"submissions" is the table with the tshirts

"votes" is the table that holds votes

"votes" structure is: ID, TEE, USER (where votes.tee == submissions.id)

This is the mysql statement I am trying:

```
SELECT 
  submissions.name,
  submissions.id,
  submissions.uploader,
  submissions.image_vote
 FROM 
  submissions,votes 
 WHERE 
  submissions.date_voted IS NOT NULL AND
  submissions.id NOT IN (SELECT tee FROM votes WHERE tee=submissions.id AND user='3')
 LIMIT 1
```

Now from what I understand I cannot use "tee=submissions.id" because it is from a query outside of this sub query. So how can I pass the sub query the ID of the tshirt I am checking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
SELECT 
  submissions.name,
  submissions.id,
  submissions.uploader,
  submissions.image_vote
 FROM 
  submissions,votes 
 WHERE 
  submissions.date_voted IS NOT NULL AND
  submissions.id NOT IN (SELECT tee FROM votes WHERE user='3')
 LIMIT 1
```

Maybe not the most efficient, but as close to your idea as possible.

Comment: That actually worked when I removed ,votes from the "FROM" table select thank you!

Answer (score 3):

sub-selects have never been a particulary shiny area in mysql.  Rather, use an outer join:

```
SELECT 
  submissions.name,
  submissions.id,
  submissions.uploader,
  submissions.image_vote
 FROM 
  submissions LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON(votes.tee=submissions.id)
 WHERE 
  submissions.date_voted IS NOT NULL AND votes.tee IS NULL
 LIMIT 1
```

the left outer join makes sure that at least one record is produced in the result per applicable record of `submissions` -- if no corresponding record exists in `votes`, then the `votes` fields in the joined record are set to NULL, so the `AND votes.whatever IS NULL` subclause picks out the joined records where no corresponding record exists in `votes`.